# Misunderstanding about Bernoulli-Euler relation?

Tags: bernoulli-polynomials

It is well - known (and famous) that the identity 
\begin{align}
 E_{n - 1} \left( x \right) = \frac{2}{n}\left[ {B_n \left( x \right) - 2^n B_n \left( {\frac{1}{2}x} \right)} \right] \\ 
 \end{align}
holds for all  $n \ge 1$  and $0 \le x \le 1$. Recall that
$B_1=-1/2$, $ E_{2n - 1} \left( 0 \right) = B_{2n + 1} \left( 0 \right) = 0,\,\,\forall n \ge 1$ and $ E_{2n} \left( 0 \right) \ne0\ne B_{2n} \left( 0 \right)  $, for all  $n \ge 1$

Now, for $x = 0$, we have
\begin{align}
 E_{n - 1} \left( 0 \right) = \frac{2}{n}\left( {1 - 2^n } \right)B_n \left( 0 \right) 
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
 E_1 \left( 0 \right) &=  - 3B_2 \left( 0 \right),\,\,{\rm{but}}\,\,E_1 \left( 0 \right) = 0 \ne B_2 \left( 0 \right)?? \\ 
 E_2 \left( 0 \right) &=  - \frac{{\left( 2 \right)\left( 7 \right)}}{3}B_3 \left( 0 \right),\,\,{\rm{but}}\,\,E_2 \left( 0 \right) \ne 0 = B_3 \left( 0 \right)?? \\ 
&\vdots 
 \end{align}
How this come? Any explanation?

---

Edit:

It is amazing to note that the absolute term in even Euler polynomials are zero. for example $E_2(x)=x^2-x$; so how $E_2(0)\ne0$?.

However $E_3(x)=x^3-\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{4}$; so how $E_3(0)=0$? .... (Big Question Mark)

I'm so confusing because on mathworld 
(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerPolynomial.html)

The even numbers are zeros while the odd numbers are not (and this my thought)

However, in several tables book  the wrote $E_{2n-1}=0$ for all $n=1,2,\cdots$ and $E_{2n}\ne0$ for example see

1- Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik
   page 1043.

2- Handbook of Mathematical Functions by Milton Abramowitz and Irene A. Stegun 
   page 805.

and others?

Answer (score 1):

It is OK. I just found the answer, the Euler numbers are simply not $E_n(0)$. It is only the value of $\frac{1}{2}$ multiplied by $2^n$. Explicitly,  $E_n=2^nE_n(\frac{1}{2})$. I thought that these numbers like Bernoulli numbers so the misunderstanding comes from this point. No one in his book say $E_n=E_n(0)$.

Sorry for confusing ...